# trying to compare file with a dictionary python 2.7 No output

Tags: python-2.7

basically i'm trying to read the file below and comparing the fruit that the person wants with the fruit in the dictionary and if the stock is above 0 then print a message saying they have been given the fruit and if stock is 0 then a message saying not fruit was given etc.

the error im getting is: "IndexError: list index out of range" on the first line of my if statement

```
[
["James Bruce", "Bananas"],
["Katherine Newton", "Bananas"],
["Deborah Garcia", "Pears"],
["Marguerite Kozlowski", "Pineapples"],
["Kenneth Fitzgerald", "Pineapples"],
["Ronald Crawford", "Bananas"],
["Donald Haar", "Apples"],
["Al Whittenberg", "Bananas"],
["Max Bergevin", "Bananas"],
["Carlos Doby", "Pears"],
["Barry Hayes", "Pineapples"],
["Donald Haar", "Bananas"]
]
```

the dictionary: {"Apples": 14, "Bananas": 14, "Pineapples": 0, "Pears": 8}
     import json

```
import json
json_Queue = open ("C:\Users\dylan gornall\Desktop\Dylan's Uni 
Work\queue.json").read ()
json.loads(json_Queue)

from ast import literal_eval
with open("C:\Users\dylan gornall\Desktop\Dylan's Uni Work\stock.json") as f:
a = f.read()
dic = literal_eval(a)

s = open ("C:\Users\dylan gornall\Desktop\Dylan's Uni Work\queue.json", 'r')
for line in s:
parts = line.split(',')
if len(parts) >1 and parts[1] == "Pears" and dic["Pears"]:
 print( parts[0] + ' has been given ' + parts[1] )

elif len(parts) >1 and parts[1] == "Apples" and dic["Apples"] >= 1 :
    print( parts[0] + ' has been given ' + parts[1] )

elif len(parts) >1 and parts[1] == "Bananas" and dic["Bananas"] >= 1 :
    print( parts[0] + ' has been given ' + parts[1] )

elif len(parts) >1 and parts[1] == "Pineapples" and dic["Pineapples"] >= 1 :
    print( parts[0] + ' has been given ' + parts[1] )

elif len(parts) >1 and parts[1] == "Pineapples" and dic["Pineapples"] == 0 :
    print(parts[0] + " was not given " + parts[1])

elif len(parts) >1 and parts[1] == "Apples" and dic["Apples"] == 0 :
    print(parts[0] + " was not given " + parts[1])

elif len(parts) >1 and parts[1] == "Pears" and dic["Pears"] == 0 :
    print(parts[0] + " was not given " + parts[1])

elif len(parts) >1 and parts[1] == "Bananas" and dic["Bananas"] == 0 :
    print(parts[0] + " was not given " + parts[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `print line` in your loop `for`, the first one is just a `[` so doing `parts = line.split(',')` give you only one element in parts, and parts[1] does not exist. You get the error you mentioned even if you check for `len(parts) >1` as python does not stop at this check and do the `parts[1]`, being then `out of range`.

Now, for your code, I think you can make it a bit shorter, if the `queue.json` is exactly how you showed it.

```
import json
json_Queue = open ("C:\Users\dylan gornall\Desktop\Dylan's Uni Work\queue.json").read()
# here I define the dict but you can do as you did, just I don't have the file
dic = {"Apples": 14, "Bananas": 14, "Pineapples": 0, "Pears": 8}
# Define s using json.loads, then s is a list of list
s = json.loads(json_Queue)
for person_fruit in s:
    #here the first person_fruit = [u'James Bruce', u'Bananas'], already a list
    person = person_fruit[0]
    fruit = person_fruit[1]
    if fruit in dic.keys():
        if dic[fruit] >=1:
            print (person + ' has been given ' + fruit)
            # here I don't know if you want to change the number of fruit in your dic but if you do, you need:
            # dic[fruit] = dic[fruit] - 1 
        else:
            print (person + " was not given " + fruit)
    else:
        print (person + " was not given " + fruit + " as we never had this fruit in our stock")
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: yeah that makes alot more sense now, thanks mate the code works aswell :)